# Customer and Orders empty after migration 1.9.2.1 to 2.3.5-p1

Tags: magento2, data-migration, data-migration-tool

Im trying to migrate data from 1.9.2.1 to 2.3.5-p1 with the data migration tools but my table customer and orders remain empty ...

The errors (who became warning with -a) are :

```
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: customer_eav_attribute. Fields: is_filterable_in_search,used_in_product_listing,store_ids,sorting_order,is_visible_on_front,type_internal,on_order_view,on_registration,is_read_only,used_in_order_grid,file_size,file_types,file_dimentions,account_filled,billing_filled,required_on_front
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input. Error: Attribute with attribute_id=135 cannot contain empty field value
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input. Error: Attribute with attribute_id=136 cannot contain empty field value
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: frontend_model. Error: Class Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default is not mapped in record attribute_id=133
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: frontend_model. Error: Class Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default is not mapped in record attribute_id=134
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: backend_model. Error: Class ewayrapid/backend_savedtokens is not mapped in record attribute_id=135
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: eav_attribute. Field: frontend_model. Error: Class Amasty_Customerattr_Model_Rewrite_Eav_Entity_Attribute_Frontend_Default is not mapped in record attribute_id=186
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: catalog_eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input_renderer. Error: Class benara_catalog/adminhtml_form_renderer_dimension is not mapped in record attribute_id=173
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: catalog_eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input_renderer. Error: Class benara_catalog/adminhtml_form_renderer_dimension is not mapped in record attribute_id=174
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][WARNING]: Incompatibility in data. Source document: catalog_eav_attribute. Field: frontend_input_renderer. Error: Class benara_catalog/adminhtml_form_renderer_dimension is not mapped in record attribute_id=175
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Customer Attributes Step]: started
[2020-06-30 06:11:28][INFO][mode: data][stage: integrity check][step: Map Step]: started
100% [============================] Remaining Time: < 1 sec
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source documents are not mapped: algoliasearch_queue,algoliasearch_queue_log,am_customerattr_guest,am_customerattr_relation,am_customerattr_relation_details,am_file,am_file_icons,am_file_stat,am_file_store,am_file_store_customer_group,am_shopby_filter,am_shopby_page,am_shopby_range,am_shopby_value,aw_blog,aw_blog_cat,aw_blog_cat_store,aw_blog_comment,aw_blog_post_cat,aw_blog_store,aw_blog_tags,bannerslider_banner,bannerslider_report,bannerslider_slider,bannerslider_value,core_directory_storage,core_file_storage,dhcarousel_group,dhcarousel_item,dhlocation_hour,dhlocation_location,dyncatprod_delaybuild,dyncatprod_rebuild,dyncatprod_subselect,mailchimp_ecommerce_sync_data,mailchimp_errors,mailchimp_sync_batches,mailchimp_webhook_request,shipping_productmatrix,smtppro_email_log,solrbridge_search_index,solrbridge_solrsearch_index_benara,solrbridge_solrsearch_logs,solrbridge_solrsearch_request,wsalogger_log
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: adminnotification_inbox. Fields: is_amasty,expiration_date
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: catalog_category_product. Fields: is_dynamic
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: eav_attribute_option. Fields: group_id
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: newsletter_subscriber. Fields: subscriber_firstname,subscriber_lastname,mailchimp_sync_delta,mailchimp_sync_error,mailchimp_sync_modified
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order. Fields: ebizmarts_abandonedcart_flag,ebizmarts_magemonkey_campaign_id,eway_transaction_id,tracking,mailchimp_campaign_id,mailchimp_abandonedcart_flag,mailchimp_landing_page
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order_address. Fields: mobile
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_order_payment. Fields: fraud_action,fraud_codes,transaction_captured,beagle_score,beagle_verification
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote. Fields: ebizmarts_abandonedcart_counter,ebizmarts_abandonedcart_flag,ebizmarts_abandonedcart_token,transaction_id,mailchimp_abandonedcart_flag,mailchimp_landing_page,mailchimp_campaign_id
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_address. Fields: mobile
[2020-06-30 06:11:30][WARNING]: Source fields are not mapped. Document: sales_flat_quote_payment. Fields: fraud_action,fraud_codes,transaction_captured,beagle_score,beagle_verification
```

Anyone got a clue why ?

Thanks

Comment: first you ignore follow this direction `<source> -> <field_rules> -> <field_rules> -> <field><EXTENSION_TABLE>.<EXTENSION_FIELD></field>`

Comment: even if its working with the -a parameter ?

Comment: i din't know but you try

Comment: https://www.goivvy.com/blog/magento-2-migration follow this its quite in depth tutorial and could be helpful for you

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I ignored the fields and documents who were causing problems, make a frsh DB and try migrate again but Customer and Orders are still empty ...